# How can I use Matplotlib to re-adjust limits of an axis (added to host plot) using the interactive zoom tool?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am displaying information with two y-axes and a common x-axis using the following script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA

#creating a host plot with x and y axis
hostplot = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

#creating a second y axis
extra_y_axis = hostplot.twinx()
extra_y_axis.set_navigate_mode(True)
extra_y_axis.set_navigate(True)
print extra_y_axis.can_zoom() #prints true on output

hostplot.set_xlabel("host_x")
hostplot.set_ylabel("host_y")
extra_y_axis.set_ylabel("extra_y")

hostplot.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
extra_y_axis.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2])

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

After this I used the 'Zoom to Rectangle' tool from the tray in the bottom-left as shown below:

[image: as shown].

And I got the following output:

[image: following output].

Please notice the y-axis scales in both the images. While the zoom functionality is working correctly for the host plot, I am unable to get the extra_y_axis to rescale and it just maintains a constant scale throughout (so I can't really zoom in on plots using the second axis).

How can I make it so that all the axes are rescaled on zooming in a small portion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've traced down your problem to the sue of the axes_grid1 toolkit. If you don't require the use of this toolkit you can easily fix your issue by initialising your figure in the usual manner:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#creating a host plot with x and y axis
fig, hostplot = plt.subplots()

#creating a second y axis
extra_y_axis = hostplot.twinx()

hostplot.set_xlabel("host_x")
hostplot.set_ylabel("host_y")
extra_y_axis.set_ylabel("extra_y")

hostplot.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
extra_y_axis.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2])

plt.show()
```

If you do want to use the toolkit then you have to add a couple of lines to get the two y axes to scale and transform together:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes import SubplotHost

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = SubplotHost(fig, 1, 1, 1)

#set the scale difference between the two y axes
aux_trans = mtransforms.Affine2D().scale(sx = 1.,sy= 1.5)
ax2 = ax1.twin(aux_trans)

fig.add_subplot(ax1)

ax1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
ax2.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2])
ax1.set_ylim(0,3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank You! But is there not a way to set sx and sy automatically? Typically the data you would have is unknown. I suppose you would manually check the max and min and set it accordingly. But I thought something like that should be done by the library.

Comment: I think that's why it's simplest to use the first method I described, then matplotlib takes care of that on it's own. I'm not an expert with the toolkit (your question was the first time I've seen it) so I can't yet comment on how to scale the axes in the toolkit.

Comment: That is what I did ultimately. I realized I did not actually need the functionality of mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 and switched to using matplotlib.pyplot alone. Anyway, thanks for the help!